# Specific constructor and initialization of fields in it

Tags: c++, class

So i need to create a class `Point` that represents the point in a two dimensional space, it must have two fields of a type double, which would represent x and y coordinate, and then i need to create a single constructor that does the following:

it needs to enable initialization of both coordinates, to enable implicit casting from type double to x-coordinate(where y is set to zero) and it needs to initialize the point to the origin of the coordinate system.

This is how i tried to do that:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y;
public:
    Point(double xx) : x(xx), y(0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

};
```

but i don't know if this is doing what it needs to do

If it says that constructor needs to initialize both coordinates , that would mean that i need to set values for them, i dont actually need to send any parameters to the constructor, however, to make implicit casting possible i need to send double and to assign it to the x coordinate. So my question is:
Is this correct? If not, why? Any help appreciated!

Comment: why are you changing the value of `x` and rewriting the same in `y`? Non explicit constructors like this are bad (https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-explicit)

Comment: The initialization list you have will initialize `x` to the value of `xx`, and the value of `y` to `0`. Then inside the constructor body you assign the value `0` to `x` (changing it value from `xx`) and also assign the value `0` to `y` (which does nothing since `y` already is `0`).

Comment: The `x = 0` and `y = 0` are wrong. Get rid of them. The rest looks correct, but you probably also need a default-constructor that initializes both to zero. And fyi, the concept your attempting is called a *conversion constructor*, and should be approached carefully, as it can make for some odd logic bugs by hiding unintended and/or undesirable conversions.

Comment: @WhozCraig well, that is the problem, i need to make one constructor that implicitly casts double to x coordinate and to set the point to the origin

Comment: @cdummie That's not a problem; that's what you *have* (less the bug about wiping out the `x` value you just properly initialized, and the needless assignment after initialization of `y`). I was only saying that unless you're code intends to *only* construct `Point` objects by conversion-construction from a single `double` expression, a default ctor may be on the menu as well; that's all.

Comment: i want to emphasize again that implicit conversions arent always desirable. They can lead to strange effects and nasty bugs later on. Its always better to be explicit. Why not write a `Point createPointFromXCoordinate(int x)` that calls a `Point(int,int)` constructor. With an implicit conversion enabled you can pass a `double` whenever a `Point` is expected. Consider a typo that would result in a nice compiler error if there was no implicit conversion. You might gain a bit in some cases, but the bugs you miss are more expensive than some extra keystrokes

Answer (score 0):

In `Point(double xx) : x(xx), y(0)` you are already initializing the members `x` and `y` (the part after the colon is called an initialization list). Since you've done this, you do not need to re-assign these members in the function body. Moreover, in what you've written, the value of `xx` is ignored because you immediately overwrite `x` with `x=0`.

From what you're saying, it sounds like you require multiple constructors `Point(void)`, `Point(double x)`, and `Point(double x, double y)`. An alternative is to use default arguments `Point(double x=0, double y=0)` but I find the former more transparent.